# NSFetchedResultsController challenge for tags and content

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Is it a way to show in a `tableView` `tags` and the relating `content`?

```
TAG1
  (TAG1 > )C1
  (TAG1 > )C2
TAG2
TAG3
  (TAG3 > )C3
  (TAG3 > )C1
```

What `predicate` and `sortDescriptors` need for `NSFetchRequest`? Is it even possible?

```
let fr = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TagOrContent")
fr.sortDescriptors = [/* .. */]
fr.predicate = NSPredicate(format: " ... ", /* .. */)
frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fr, managedObjectContext: mainMOC, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
frc!.delegate = self
frc!.performFetch(nil)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you exactly want to do ? That is possible simply by using Tag as the main entity associated with the NSFetchRequest and tagContents are the toMany value that each tag has.

Comment: in the same table I want to show `tag` and `content` items, and wants get notified when new `tag` or `content` was added, removed, updated ..

Comment: Just return the number of rows based on the number of tags and the number of sum of the contents that each tag has. This might be easier if you use some sectioning and then on each sections you could then assign the content based on what each tag has

Comment: I want to show / hide `tag`s, so tag should be a row and not a section

Comment: Ok, that depends on how you implement it, you could very well reload some sections only and then hide the contents associated with it.

Comment: What information are you showing about tags, and what information about content?

Comment: both `tag` and `content` is a short text 10-30 chararters

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne but how do you select a section? it has only 22px height. Should I enable tap event on section header and increase height?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use 2 FRCs - 1 for `Tag`s and another for `Content`.

The `Tag` FRC controls the sections in the table view, but not rows. `Tag` information is shown in section headers. The `sectionNameKeyPath` needs to be set so that each `Tag` is returned in a separate section. You can add a button to each section header to detect taps to manage collapse of the section.

The `Content` FRC exists only to monitor the context for changes and cause reloads of the section to which they belong (based on the `Tag` they are connected to).

If you want to hide a full tag section then you should remove the rows and set the section header height to zero, so the section still exists but isn't visible. Otherwise you will have indexing issues.